# Application ID for Windows phone 7 and Windows phone 8 apps

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

Should applications which are same but for different devices (Windows phone 7 and Windows phone 8) have the same GUID number in WMAppManifest.xml ProductID field?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The app Guid number will be changed when you submit the app into the market, if you submit two xaps in the same app for different OS versions the app guid will be the same.